# Mongoose find always returning true when it shouldn't

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I’m using Mongoose.js to interface with my Mongo database. This function searches through my `Location` names and should be logging `not found` to the console instead of `found`, as I don't have a `Location` with the name `!@£`.

```
Location.find({name: "!@£"}, function(err, obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  if (!err) {
    console.log("found");
  } else {
    console.log("not found");
  }
});
```

This is what is logging out to my console:

```
[]
found
```

The expected behaviour should be for it to log `not found` to the console. Here's a dump of the `Location` model data:

```
[
  {
     "_id":"5384c421af3de75252522aa2",
     "name":"London, UK",
     "lat":51.508515,
     "lng":-0.12548719999995228,
     "__v":0,
     "modified":"2014-05-27T16:58:09.546Z",
     "search_count":1
  },
  {
     "_id":"5384c766af3de75252522ab4",
     "name":"Paris, France",
     "lat":48.856614,
     "lng":2.3522219000000177,
     "__v":0,
     "modified":"2014-05-27T17:12:06.990Z",
     "search_count":1
  },
  {
     "_id":"53851a213a33fe392b758046",
     "name":"Zagreb, Croatia",
     "lat":45.8150108,
     "lng":15.981919000000062,
     "__v":0,
     "modified":"2014-05-27T23:05:05.306Z",
     "search_count":1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback interface semantics are not what you think.

- `err` means the query failed entirely due to an error like the DB being unreachable. It has no meaning with regard to whether documents matched or not
- `obj` is an array of results, which you should name "locations" IMHO to keep things clear. If no documents match the query, this array will be empty. If some match, they will be in the array.

So there are 3 total states to consider: error, success with no matches, success with some matches.